# Scrapy0.22: An error occured while connecting: <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, twisted, web-crawler

Good morning,

I get a connection error while executing one of my spiders:

```
2014-02-28 10:21:00+0400 [butik] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.butik.ru/> (failed 1 times): An error occurred while connecting: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.].
```

Afterwards the spider shuts down.

All other spiders with a smiliar structure are running smoothly, but this one:

```
class butik(Spider):
    name = "butik"
    allowed_domains = ['butik.ru']
    start_urls      = ['http://www.butik.ru/']

    def parse(self, response): 
        sel = Selector(response)
        print response.url
        maincats = sel.xpath('//div[@id="main_menu"]//a/@href').extract()
        for maincat in maincats:
            maincat = 'http://www.butik.ru'+ maincat 
            request = Request(maincat, callback=self.categories)
            yield request
```

I'm quite clueless which steps to take in order to fix this issue and am glad for any hints and answers. If additional informations are needed I would be happy to provide the neccessary code.

Thanks in advance

J

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `urllib2` instead. I also got similar problem when I'm using `scrapy` to crawl a page, but I fix this problem by using `urllib2` inside a `parse`:

```
import urllib2

def parse(self,response):
    # ...
    url = 'www.example.com'
    req = urllib2.Request(url,data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    the_page = response.read()
    # ...
```